# Unable to access to response from PHP SoapClient()

Tags: php, soap-client

I have setup SoapClient in php like:

```
<?php

  $wsdl = 'Wsdl-url';
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
  $ticketinfo = array('strWorkItemType' => 'Service Request', 'strID' => 'SR14270425', 'strGlobalID' => '', 'strStatus' => '', 'strTitle'=> '', 'strDesc' => '', 'strCreateDate' => '', 'strStartDate' => '', 'strEndDate' => '');
  $result = $client->GetSCSMWorkItem($ticketinfo);

  var_dump($result);
?>
```

Result =

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetSCSMWorkItemResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["SCSMResponseData"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (19) { ["AUEmail"]=> string(8) "cblancmr" ["AUFirstName"]=> NULL ["AULastName"]=> NULL ["AUPhone"]=> NULL ["AssignedTo"]=> string(7) "jangele" ["Classification"]=> string(15) "Other - Request" ["CreatedDate"]=> string(19) "2/3/2016 6:00:00 AM" ["Description"]=> string(1523) "I...
```

How can I print AssignedTo string value?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure, but I think it's a nested object. Please comment down if I'm wrong. But I would guess something like this:

```
    $result->GetSCSMWorkItemResult->SCSMResponseData->AssignedTo;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object, so you will want to do:

```
echo $result->AssignedTo;
```

Comment: I got nothing :( its not working. I have blank page.